# Sometimes varnish cache an index of (?C=N;O=D)

Tags: wordpress, apache, varnish, indexof, varnish-vcl

I have a issue with one server, this server hosts an wordpress with wp-super-cache, apache 2.2 and varnish 3.

Sometimes the varnish caches an blank page or index of page with this query "/?C=N;O=D", When it happens the number of real time visitors really drops, like the image below:

[visitors drop image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrVKn.png)

Sometimes the user number drops from 700 to 50 very fast.

The VLC that I use is it: https://gist.github.com/diegoos/f1411ca56d061ed5ae25

Does anyone know what can it be?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but why the "|" at the end of some of your regexes?

Comment: Hi @jdewald, It was by mistake. But, I removed the varnish 3, I installed varnish 4 and I changed the VCL.  This did not solved my problem, but improved somewhat.